# C - sorting a list on words in a text file

Tags: c, sorting, io, quicksort

Wondering what method would be most suitable, and maybe, if someone would be so kind, how to start such a function for:

```
AWord
DWord
CWord
BWord
```

To end up in a new text file like:

```
AWord
BWord
CWord
DWord
```

At the moment, my program, reads each word line by line `fgets()` and does some stuff to it, capitalises the first letter etc. Once all that is done, a new text file is created, text.out.

I then want to sort it into alphabetical order, since all the words are only alphabetic, some maybe terminating with a number.

Thanks, any help is appreciated!

T.C

Comment: Take a look at the standard [`qsort()`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/) function.

Comment: I don't have an array of words though, its just a file containing words, each word is read into a single array, modified, then outputted.

Comment: Or, if you already have a file, you can delegate to UNIX `sort`, which knows some things about sorting files that you probably don't. It's not as efficient in code, but it will be much tighter and better than what you can do yourself if you need to ask SO about it. @Oli's solution is - don't output to file, build an array instead, then `qsort()` it.

Comment: Unless @Amadan this is homework.

Comment: @user1048116: Obviously, in order to sort the file, you will need to read it all into memory first.  (Well, there are mechanisms to do it all in-place, but they're probably not what you want here.)

Comment: It isn't a homework task, I am currently away from Uni, just working ahead on some C really.

Comment: Well that's great then. Today's task: Learn how `qsort()` works!

Comment: ... and also learn how to manage an unknown amount of lines of an unknown length each! ;-)

Comment: Also, how to dynamically allocate memory, count lines, create array of strings. 1) find out file size with fseek and ftell, 2) allocate a chunk with malloc, 3) read the whole file with fread, 4) replace all newlines with 0 and count them, 5) allocate an array of `char*` and collect all addresses of line beginnings and 6) qsort the lot.

Answer (score 1):

You said that you don't have an array of words, but that you read each line into a separate character array.  This is what you need to fix.  Declare `char *lines[MAXLINES]`, an array of every line from your input file.  Read each line from your input file in to that array.  Then you can sort that array before putting it back out.

This is pretty much identical to the concepts presented in K&R Section 5.6 and 5.11.